# Rails 4. Gem will_paginate. Change pagination links set on ajax request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

Dears, i have trouble with pagination links.
I use rails 4.2 and will_paginate gem.

I have @students and one set of pagination links. 
I have search form, which gets data using ajax request. After this request i have new set of pagination links.

I need:
- to draw new set of pagination links
- make active link to first page

I have now:
- old pagination links with old active page number

```
<div id='paginator'><%= will_paginate @students %></div>
<script>
   //some get function to get data
   drawTable(data);
   function drawTable(data) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        drawRow(data[i]);
      }
      document.getElementById("paginator").innerHTML = "";
      $('#paginator').append($('<%= will_paginate @students %>'));
  }
</script>
```

As you see, i remove content of paginator div and draw it again. But i have the old link anyways.

Guys, what i'm doing wrong???
Where is the shit? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the content before appending it. try this:

`$('#paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript( will_paginate(@students)) %>');`

Just replace above code with your .append line.

Comment: Unfortunately, no result. I have my old set of links

Comment: Its because you have written an inline js. This will always evaluate to `<%= will_paginate @students %>` to the same as the first page load. either you should render remote data with `.js.erb` or you should fetch the pagination data along with the other data you fetch from server.

Comment: Best would be that where you are sending the ajax call for search just replace the pagination links with code above inside the search.js.erb

Comment: But i can't move js to another file. Then it would not find some ruby code like student_path method which i use in my js

Comment: Meer, thanx for answer. I decided to fetch new links at server side too.